# Как сделать чтобы картинка останавливалась у края

Tags: c#, wpf

Образно говоря, есть изображение танка, который может двигаться в любые стороны. Но, когда танк выезжает за пределы игрового поля, изображение танка пропадает, а необходимо, чтобы танк останавливался рядом с краем поля (изображение не должно пропадать).

Вот код перемещения изображения:

```
    private void KeyDowdDo(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left + 3, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);


        if (e.Key == Key.Left)
            image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left - 3, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);

        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top - 3, 0, 0);

        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top + 3, 0, 0);
    }
```

помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: Нужно сравнить крайнее положение и положение танка, если они равны, то при дальнейшем нажатии кнопки в этом направлении задавать скорость 0, по типу `image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);`

Comment: А как узнать крайнее положение

Comment: Либо задать изначально, либо экспериментально измерить

Comment: А можете привести пример типа кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях не удобно писать код, вот пример

```
if (e.Key == Key.Down)
   if(image.Margin.Top>0)
      image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top + 3, 0, 0);
   else
      image.Margin = new Thickness(image.Margin.Left, image.Margin.Top, 0, 0);
```